# Raise a ticket to issue tracking from external web application

Tags: java, web-hosting, technical-support

I don't know if it's the right place to post this question but, to improve my productivity I need to install an open source issue-tracking system to keep tracks of all bugs and information about the completion.

There are a lot of open source systems to do that but I'm looking for one which could be hosted on PHP / MySql / Linux server and, in particular allows to raise a ticket via rest or soap from my Spring webapp (I thought to create a simple form in my webApp to submit a ticket).

I took a look to The Bug Genie, Mantis and WebIssues and the first two are very hard to be used by non IT user. WebIssues seems to be very easy also for my customers that just need to take a look to the ticket resolution status.

Any tips?

---

Note I prefer to install my own system in order to pay only one hosting service.

Answer (score 1):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org). Or [chili](https://www.chiliproject.org/). Both are essentially the same, both let your do email bug reports pretty easily. They also have rest APIs that are pretty straightforward.

Runs on ruby but that co-exists just fine with the standard LAMP stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) meets all of your requirements, and I used to like it, back when I used it a few years ago.  It's well established, uses LAMP stack and I think probably a good place to look.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to install your own?  There are several hosted solutions out there.

Comment: I prefer to pay only one hosting service.

Comment: There are free hosted services, assuming your product is FOSS

Comment: My project is not FOSS